# How do I pass this param properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make an API request with a *text* param, with information I currently have in `params[:brand][:tag_list]` which seems to be saved as a single comma-delimited string. What's the correct way to make the API request?

**Controller code**:

```
current_user.tag(@brand, :with => params[:brand][:tag_list], :on => :tags)

url = "http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json"
@sentiment_response = url.to_uri.get(
  :api_key => 'MY_KEY',
  :text => :tag_list ).deserialize #This is what I'm currently using and is wrong
```

**Response codes from log**:

```
<- (GET 49996946161 2204098100) http://www.viralheat.com:80/api/sentiment/review.json?api_key=MY_KEY&text=tag_list
-> (GET 49996946161 2204098100) 200 OK (62 bytes 3.09s)
```

Comment: :tag_list is a list of tags in a hash i.e. "cat", "dog", "mouse" so the response should be: http://www.viralheat.com:80/api/sentiment/review.json?api_key=MY_KEY&text=cat&dog&mouse

Comment: `http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json?api_key=MY_KEY&text=cat&dog&mouse` is almost certainly not what you mean; this creates the pairs "text=cat", "dog", and "mouse", which is nonsensical. Also, you are not passing an array, you ar passing a symbol. ":tag_list" is by definition *not a hash*. You probably mean something like params[:brand][:tag_list], but even then, it's not clear how that hash is supposed to be converted into a string for this api. Because the url you say it should form is non correct.

Comment: Sure. But the tags input in a form get saved to that symbol. I want to get those tags out of that symbol in order to send them [in the correct URL format].

Comment: You are not using accurate terminology. *Nothing* gets saved into a symbol. A symbol is just a literal name. Just like you can't store a hash in the string `"tag_list"`, you can't store a hash in the symbol `:tag_list`. *A symbol is just a name*

Comment: Where the form data gets stored is in *params*. `params` is a hash, and it uses symbols as the hash keys. You are looking for `params[:brand][:tag_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the docs for `viralheat`, it looks like their api accepts exactly two parameters: `api_key`, and `text`. Assuming `params[:brand][:tag_list]` a comma-delimited string, you can form your request like so:

```
current_user.tag(@brand, :with => params[:brand][:tag_list], :on => :tags)

url = "http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json"
@sentiment_response = url.to_uri.get(
  :api_key => 'MY_KEY',
  :text => params[:brand][:tag_list].split(',').join('&') ).deserialize
```

This should create the url:

```
http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json?api_key=MY_KEY&text=cat%26dog%26​mouse
```

`params[:brand][:tag_list].split(',')` breaks your string into an array, and `join('&')` turns it back into a string, but this time delimited by ampersands (which seems to be what you want, based on what you said in a comment on your original post). Your uri.get method should escape the ampersands in the uri, which is why you see the `%26`s in the final url. This is correct.

Comment: Ok now that we're past the erroneous nomenclature, this is what I want, expect I'll get a no method error because it's just a comma-delimited string and not an array of strings.

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer to reflect that the input is a comma-delimited string (and still assuming you want to pass an &-delimited string to the api?).

Comment: Cheers dude. Very blind of me not to use split()